# where to define variable for a for each loop?

Tags: java

can you please advise me why my first code attempt didn't work :

```
public void listAllFiles()
{
    for(String filename : files)
    {
        int position = 0;
        System.out.println(position + ": " + filename);
        position = position + 1;
    }
}
```

it kept printing position at 0 without iterating position

but it seems to work after i did it this way:

```
public void listAllFiles()
{
     int position = 0;
     for(String filename : files)
     {               
           System.out.println(position + ": " + filename);
           position = position + 1;
     }
 }
```

I don't understand why the position + 1 was not being executed, is it because we are not meant to define variables inside for loops or am i missing something in my code.

Comment: This question would be better suited for stackoverflow. Anyway in the first case at each iteration you're reassigning 0 to your position variable that's why it always show 0. In this case it would be better use a normal [for loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html)  instead of a foreach

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where should variables be declared](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/233695/where-should-variables-be-declared)

Answer (score 7):

In the first code, you are re-declaring/initializing the int so every time it goes through the loop, it resets the value to the default. In the second one, taking the initialization out of the loop stops it from resetting. If you're iterating, you should always have something like this:

```
    int x = 0;
    for(int y = 0; y<=10; y++)
    {
        //do something
        x++;
    }
    System.out.println(x); //10
```

Answer (score 2):

The variables declared inside the loop are only visible there, so you are declaring the variable, initializing it with 0, then increasing it and then forgetting everything about it.

In the next iteration of the loop, you are again declaring it, initializing it with 0, increasing, forgetting, and so on.

If you want to keep the variable between the loop runs, you need to declare it outside of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Well the statements we are putting inside scope of FOR loop are executed on each iteration.
So if we don not want to reinitialize variables every iteration,Variables should be declared outside the FOR loop.
Below is short method we can achieve this :

```
for(int x = 0; x<=10)
{
    //do something
    x++;
}
```